# SQL Statement two columns value return single value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Please suggest best way to construct SQL statement thanks a lot!

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MQN5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select id,[date],(case  when refund = 1 then 'R'
                        when voidstatus = 0 then 'C'
                        when  voidstatus = 1 then 'V'
                        else '' end
                ) as [status],grossamt
from    trans
```

Comment: Look at the conditions again, thats not what he requested

Comment: this work fine. thx bro!